# How do the normal and parallel components add up to more than the total force of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors, free-body-diagram

When calculating the forces on an inclined plane I understand to separate the gravity vector which is perpendicular to the ground into a parallel and normal vectors.  How is it possible that the normal force and parallel force of the incline add up to more total force then the gravity vector ?  How is it possible to get more force out of the force that is initially being split into 2 components?

Comment: What makes you say that they add up to more than the total force?

Comment: I assume you're wondering why you can't just add the magnitude of two perpendicular forces to get the magnitude of the resultant force?

Comment: Do you have an issue with the idea that if two forces are acting in opposite directions they need to be subtracted to find the net force; whereas when they are in the same direction they are added?

Comment: What I am saying is if you take the force of gravity x mass.  That number will always be less then the amount of normal force + parallel force on an inclined plane.  I don’t understand how if gravity is putting x amount of force down on a mass how when you divide it into components the combined force of the components is equal to more force..  shouldn’t you be able to add parallel force and normal (perpendicular) force together and it should be equal to the force of gravity straight down on the mass??  How do you create more force ?

Comment: Firstly force is not conserved, rather energy is conserved. So to remove that from the problem I think you should consider lengths of sides of a 345 triangle. The lengths of the shorter sides add up to 7 (>5). 
The path along the 2 short sides is indirect, but achieves the same translation as the path on the long side. Does this give you an issues?

Comment: Adding vectors requires taking their direction into account. Take two vectors of magnitude 1. If they are perpendicular, you're getting sqrt(2) instead of 2. If they face opposite directions you're getting 0. Only if they are parallel 1+1=2.

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible that the normal force and parallel force of the
>   incline add up to more total force then the gravity vector ?

I wonder if you're decomposing the gravity vector correctly ***or*** whether you're adding them correctly.

Have a look at this:

[image: Forces on an incline]

The gravity vector (perpendicular to the horizontal) is correctly decomposed into the normal ($F_2$) and the incline parallel component ($F_1$).

Basic trigonometry tells us that the **scalars** of these vectors are:

$F_2=mg\cos\alpha$

$F_1=mg\sin\alpha$

The sum of the vectors $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$ however, is a **vector sum** and the scalar of this sum ($mg$) **is not simply the sum of the scalars $F_1$ and $F_2$**. In fact, the scalar of the resultant $mg$ is obtained by Pythagoras:

$$(mg)^2=F_1^2+F_2^2$$

With the above:

$$(mg)^2=(mg\sin\alpha)^2+(mg\cos\alpha)^2$$
$$=(mg)^2(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)$$
$$mg=mg$$

Simply adding the scalars has no meaning at all. This is true for all vectors, except where there is no angle between them at all.

The sum $mg\cos\alpha+mg\sin\alpha$ **has no physical meaning** and must be ignored.

---

As a little aside, here's another case of two force vectors $\vec{F_a}$ and $\vec{F_b}$, acting on the same point and their *resultant force* $\vec{F_R}$:

[image: Resultant force]

Here too the resultant vector $\vec{F_R}$ is obtained by the **vector addition** of $\vec{F_a}$ and $\vec{F_b}$:

$$\vec{F_R} =\vec{F_a} + \vec{F_b}$$

The scalar $F_R$ here is obtained by an [extended version of Pythagoras](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-5/non-right-triangle-trigonometry/) (where the angle between both components is not a right angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$) and, as in the simple right angled case above, not by simply adding the scalars $F_a$ and $F_b$.